# How can I implement a callback after layer.destroyChilden()

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

This is for homework and it has an annoying bug I can't solve after hours of struggle.

http://canvaseu.chrisloughnane.net/

When on the eu map clicking a country path fires the bound event.

This event destroys the layers children and loads the country. BUT if you click and quickly move the mouse and let go the button the country loads but the country path from the eu remains. This is best demonstrated with Spain as shown in the screen grab.

I am hoping a callback after `mapLayer.destroyChildren();` to then call the load function would solve my problem.

This can be a little difficult to replicate.

I'm sure my control is too tied up with my view but I haven't been able to see a solution to separate them neatly.

[image]

**** EDIT ****

I came up with a solution that works partially but I think this is terrible hack code, I added to the mousedown binding `down = true;` and added checks to the `mouseout` binding, please see below.
What I think is happening is when you move the mouse and let the button go very quickly the  `mouseover` binding is over riding the mouseup.

This solution isn't ideal, after loading a number of countries and mouseover on regions the canvas response slows down.

---

`Event Binding`

```
path.on('mousedown touchstart', function() 
{
            down = true;
    this.setStroke('red');
    this.moveTo(topLayer);
    /****
     * Handle if the path we are displaying in canvas is the eu
     * to allow selection and load of country path point data.
     */
    if (associativeCountryArray[lastCountry].getText() == 'eu') 
    {
        associativeCountryArray[lastCountry].setFill('#bbb');
        associativeCountryArray[lastCountry].setFontStyle('normal');
        countrynames[lastCountry].selected = false;
        this.moveTo(mapLayer);
        mapLayer.destroyChildren();
        lastCountry = this.getName();
        countrynames[this.getName()].selected = true;
        associativeCountryArray[this.getName()].setFill("rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")");
        associativeCountryArray[this.getName()].setFontStyle('bold');
        loadPaths(this.getName().replace(/\s/g, ''));
        countryNameLayer.draw();
    }
    else
    {
        window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + this.getName(),'_blank');
    }
    topLayer.drawScene();
});



path.on('mouseout', function() 
{
    if(!down)
    {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        this.setFill('#eee');
        this.setStrokeWidth(settings.strokewidthstart);
        /****
         * On hover, only change colour of country names around edge of canvas if we are on the 'eu' map
         */
        if (lastCountry == 'eu') 
        {
            associativeCountryArray[this.getName()].setFill('#bbb');
            associativeCountryArray[this.getName()].setFontStyle('normal');
        }
        this.setStroke('#555');
        this.moveTo(mapLayer);
        writeMessage('');
        topLayer.draw();
        countryNameLayer.draw();
    }
    else
    {
        down = false;
    }
});
path.on('mouseup touchend', function() 
{
    this.setStroke('black');
    topLayer.drawScene();
    down = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

Send the container (group,layer) you want to clear and the callback you want triggered.

```
function myDestroyChildren(container,callback) {
    var children = container.getChildren();
    while(children.length > 0) {
        children[0].destroy();
    }
    callback();
}
```

Comment: cheers markE. I find callbacks are still a source of 'huh?'. As soon as I read your method I got it. Though adding your method causes unusual behaviour, the whole thing needs a rewrite which will have to wait until after exams. I submitted with my solution using a boolean as a semaphore.